# Radio Button to Show Another Set of Form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, radio-button

I want to achieve a form whereby when a radio-A is selected, it will show another set of radio buttons.

I have already make the form

```
<div id="numberofpax">
    <p><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="ToggleDivs" onclick="Toggle('Div2-selfdrive');" value="2" class="2paxcar">
    <label for="radio1"><img src="images/form/2pax.png"></label></p>

    <p><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="ToggleDivs" onclick="Toggle('Div3-selfdrive');" value="3" class="3paxcar" checked>
    <label for="radio2"><img src="images/form/3pax.png"></label></p>

    <p><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="ToggleDivs" onclick="Toggle('Div4-selfdrive');" value="4" class="4paxcar">
    <label for="radio3"><img src="images/form/4pax.png"></label> </p>

    <p><input type="radio" id="radio4" name="ToggleDivs" onclick="Toggle('Div5-selfdrive');" value="5" class="5paxcar">
    <label for="radio4"><img src="images/form/5pax.png"></label></p>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['ToggleDivs']))
{
    if($_POST['ToggleDivs'] = '2')
    {
        echo "2 PAX";
    }   
    elseif($_POST['ToggleDivs'] = '3')
    {   
        echo "3 PAX";
    }
    elseif($_POST['ToggleDivs'] = '4')
    {   
        echo "4 PAX";
    }   
    else
    {
        echo "5 PAX";
    }
}
?>
```

I believe it is the IF ELSE STATEMENT ISSUE? but somehow i cant make it work?

---

I think i should be more specific on what i want to achieve.

```
[radiobutton-pax1][radiobutton-pax2][radiobutton-pax3][radiobutton-pax4]

[radiobutton-hotel1][radiobutton-hotel2] 

[radiobutton-car1] [radiobutton-car2] [radiobutton-car3] [radiobutton-car4]
```

So by default, 'radiobutton-pax1' & 'radiobutton-hotel1' & 'radiobutton-car1' is selected by default which I have already achieve.

And when user select 'radiobutton-pax1', 'radiobutton-car1 to 4' will appear.
And when user select 'radiobutton-pax2', 'radiobutton-car1 to 4' will appear.
And when user select 'radiobutton-pax3', 'radiobutton-car2 to 3' will appear.
And when user select 'radiobutton-pax4', 'radiobutton-car3 to 4' will appear.

I have also achieve that. The problem is the default radiobutton checked suppose to be the lowest of each selection. For example;

If radiobutton-pax1 is selected, the default selection will be radiobutton-car1
If radiobutton-pax2 is selected, the default selection will be radiobutton-car1
If radiobutton-pax3 is selected, the default selection will be radiobutton-car2
If radiobutton-pax4 is selected, the default selection will be radiobutton-car3

This is where i'm stuck.

Comment: if you are trying to achieve what you are saying by above code then it will not work.

first of all the radio buttons will not trigger your form to submit because of which you values will not be posted.

second of all, your comparison operators are set as assignment operators in your php codes. 

can you please post to codes along with your form so that we can assist you with this.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP the `=` operator is to assign a value to a variable.

You are looking for the comparison `==` operator which tests if expression1 is equal to expression2 and will evaluate that to true or false.

Please see:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['ToggleDivs'])){
            if($_POST['ToggleDivs'] == '2'){
            echo "2 PAX";
            }   
            elseif($_POST['ToggleDivs'] == '3'){   
            echo "3 PAX";
            }
            elseif($_POST['ToggleDivs'] == '4'){   
            echo "4 PAX";
            }   
            else{
             echo "5 PAX";
            }
            }
        ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Alternatively though, you may find a switch statement more useful than a long set of Else if's. E.g:

```
<?php
  switch($_POST['ToggleDivs']){
    case '2': 
      echo "2 PAX";
      break;
    case '3': 
      echo "3 PAX";
      break;
    case '4': 
      echo "4 PAX";
      break;
    default:
      echo 'error';
      break;
  }
```

Comment: it shows error which is default. Even though i change to 2 pax or so it will still show the default value

Comment: that is because your POST array is empty. It will initiates the switch statement and doesn't match with any cases and in the end displays the contents in the default section.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the `==`?

```
if($_POST['ToggleDivs'] == '2'){
```

Comment: @smartans I assume that your php code is on different page, correct? Also please be sure to check if `isset($_POST['ToggleDivs'])` is returning a value.